# SQL - Sum Values with Same Date, for Each Date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a dataset that looks like this

```
Enc_ID |  date   |  P1  |  P3  |
--------------------------------
1      | 11/1/17 |  1   | NULL |
2      | 11/1/17 | NULL |  1   |
3      | 11/1/17 |  1   | NULL |
4      | 11/2/17 |  1   | NULL |
5      | 11/2/17 | NULL |  1   |
```

ie each row is an encounter, and there can be (are always) multiple encounters on any given day.

I need to calculate a running sum of P1 and P3 for each day. So:

```
  date  | sum_p1 | sum_p3 |
---------------------------
11/1/17 |   2    |   1    |
11/2/17 |   3    |   2    |
```

Then I need to perform this calculation for each of these sums for each date like this:

```
(sum_p1 - sum_p3) / sum_p1
```

So I ultimately need a table that would show

```
  date  | dropout rate
----------------------
11/1/17 | 50%
11/2/17 | 33%
```

I'm trying to do this in Superset, so I cannot use any `JOINS`. I've tried some kind of nested `GROUP BY` but `MySQL (5.7.20)` doesn't like it.

This is my current query, but it only returns the `SUM` of p1 and p3 FOR each date, not AS OF each date.

```
SELECT encounter_date AS __timestamp,
       (SUM(p1) - SUM(p3)) / SUM(p1) AS pd
FROM encounter
WHERE encounter_date >= '2016-11-06 00:00:00.000000'
  AND encounter_date <= '2017-11-06 17:00:29.000000'
GROUP BY encounter_date
ORDER BY encounter_date ASC
LIMIT 50000
OFFSET 0
```

Comment: Is it MySQL or Postgresql?

Comment: thanks @Gordon for formatting help :)

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto currently I'm working in MySQL but I believe we're switching to Postgres soon, so I tagged with both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL, use variables or subqueries.  Variables is easier in this case:

```
select encounter_date, p1, p3,
       (@p1 := @p1 + p1) as running_p1,
       (@p3 := @p3 + p3) as running_p3
from (select encounter_date, count(p1) as p1, count(p3) as p3
      from encounter e
      where encounter_date >= '2016-11-06 00:00:00.000000' and encounter_date <= '2017-11-06 17:00:29.000000'
      group by encounter_date
      order by encounter_date
     ) e cross join
     (select @p1 := 0, @p3 := 0) params;
```

For your final calculation, use this as a subquery to do the final calculation.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean with "For your final calculation, use this as a subquery to do the final calculation."? (I am brand new to SQL)

thanks :)

Comment: @ClayCrosby . . . You should learn what subqueries/derived tables are.

Comment: Made a quick edit to the second and third rows but this worked. Thank you @Gordon!!

Answer (score 0):

I would do it sequentially with 2 connected queries:

```
SELECT encounter_date as `date`, (1-`sum_p3`/`sum_p1`) as `dropout rate` FROM (
 SELECT encounter_date, SUM(p1) as `sum_p1`, SUM(p3) as `sum_p3`
 FROM encounter
 WHERE encounter_date >= '2016-11-06 00:00:00.000000'
  AND encounter_date <= '2017-11-06 17:00:29.000000'
 GROUP BY encounter_date
 ORDER BY encounter_date ASC
) as `grouped`
```

Comment: This still returns the values **for** each day and not **as of** each day